# Android - User Interface to Control Number Input

Tags: android, input, widget, numbers, controls

I am trying to make a nice interface to control the input of the number of cars to my application..

I would like to have something like the icon of the car and then an upper arrow and lower arrow, so the user could control the amount of the cars in the application.. you get it?

The design would be something like this picture:
[image]

But I don't know if the Android Library was something already to handle this.. is there something ? Or do I need to make the widget myself ?

If I need to do it myself what would be the best way ? Using 3 images, and adding a image listener to the arrows images ? And how would I put it on the screen aligned like that ? Imagine that I would have cars and bikes.. and would be in the same line ?

Thanks alot in advance !

Comment: It depends on how you want it displayed in your app. If you want it in whatever activity you are displaying, you would just add it to the XML file you are using as the view for your activity.

Comment: That didn't helped much mate x)

Comment: You can use [Picker](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/pickers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you make 3 separate images stored in your drawable folders:  upArrow.png, downArrow.png, and car.png (or whatever type of image, your choice).  To make them vertically aligned like that, you can place them in a linear layout with a vertical orientation.  Since you want the arrows to be clickable, I would make them ImageButtons and use the arrow images as backgrounds for the buttons.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/upButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/upArrow.png" 
        android:onClick="incrementCars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/carImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"
        android:contentDescription="This is a car" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/downArrow.png" 
        android:onClick="decrementCars" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can do the same thing for bikes, just switching out the center image and the onClick methods.

Comment: Yes I guess that's the only way.. I can't adapt the Picker class ? Make my custom class ? instead of a EditBox I would use an image? its possible? Thanks alot mate ;)